# How to download dependencies using Bazel?

Tags: maven, build, bazel

I am new to Bazel. I need to download external dependency jar files using Bazel. Where to configure to download external jar files. I tried to add jar files in BUILD and WORKSPACE files , but not working.

**Workspace file**

```
maven_server(name="myserver",url="https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-java")
maven_jar(name="flink-java",artifact="org.apache.flink:filnk-java:jar:1.2.0",server="myserver")
bind(name="flink-java",actual="@flink-java//jar")
```

**Build file**

```
java_binary(
name="read_files",
srcs = glob(["ReadFiles.java"]),
main_class="com.ibm.cdo.gts.contracts.pipeline.preprocess.ReadFiles",
deps=["//external:flink-java"],
)
```

Comment: Did my answer solve your issue? If so I'd appreciate you marking it as accepted.

Comment: Chowdam: it is not mandatory to accept answers here, to vote on them, or to reply to them, but you have signed in since seeing Ittai's message, so it'd be nice to respond in some fashion.

Answer (score 3):

The logical mistake you have there is that the workspace name (`flink-java`) is illegal [see here](https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/be/workspace.html#maven_jar_name) and [here](https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/be/functions.html#workspace). What is needed is to change the `-` to `_` in `maven_jar` and of course the reference in the `bind`.

```
maven_jar(name="flink_java",artifact="org.apache.flink:flink-java:jar:1.2.0")
bind(name="flink-java",actual="@flink_java//jar")
```

Two more mistakes you had in the above were:

1. In the artifact coordinates you wrote `filnk-java` when you needed `flink-java`
2. The mvnrepository URL you used doesn't seem to be legal. I tried a few variants but couldn't get it to work. Additionally from the site they seem to link downloads to Maven Central itself so I'm not sure they server the jars. Having said that since Bazel fallbacks to Maven Central I just omitted the `maven_server` and the build passes. If you need help with the `maven_server` part and you need to use a private Maven repository please double check the URL first.

PS: It would have really helped if you added to your question the Bazel outputs since I needed to create my own workspace to know what were the problems you encountered.